# Calculate hockey puck bouncing off rubber bumper

Tags: projectile-physics

I am very new to game development (or any type of development for that matter) and I am trying to figure out how I would calculate a hockey type puck bouncing off a rubber bumper placed at a 45 degree angle. The puck could hit the bumper at any angle during play. Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like a pretty standard [elastic collision](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=elastic+collision), which is documented extensively in physics tutorials and past Q&A here. What has your research turned up so far, and how have you tried applying it in your game? Have you run into trouble with any particular step?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am so new to this I had not even heard of elastic collision. The main focus I had researched was a ball type object bouncing off a wall, but, nothing seemed to fit - after your comment I can now research (correctly) elastic collision instead. My project is very early stages of screen design, so I am not at a stage where I could implement anything. I just needed help with the type of calculation to use. Thank you again for your help :)